# Evaluate the limit if it exists

Tags: complex-analysis

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}1+z^2 & \text{if }z\not=i \\ 4i & \text{if }z=i \end{cases}$$

i.) evaluate limit as $z$ approaches $i$ if it exists

ii.) evaluate the limit as $z$ approaches $-i$ if it exists

iii.) where is $f(z)$ continuous? give a complete explanation

Sorry i am not familiar with the formatting. Can someone help me solve this problem and explain it in layman's terms?

my attempt at the solution:
converting $f(z)$ to $f(x+iy)$ and then finding the limit of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$?

Answer (score 0):

You know, that the function $g(z)=1+z^2$ is continuous. Thus you can say $$\lim_{z\rightarrow i, z \neq i} f(z) = \lim_{z\rightarrow i, z \neq i} 1+ z^2 = 1+\left(\lim_{z\rightarrow i, z \neq i} z\right)^2 = 1+i^2 = 0$$
You can compute the limit for $z\rightarrow-i$ in the same way...

Comment: and for part iii) how do i explain where f(z) is continuous?

Comment: @user214010: What is your guess? What have you tried so far? If something is still unclear it's a good thing to ask a new question where you also explain, what you have done so far...